# What is the meaning of "WES" "LEG" or "CAD" written next to a prescription?

Tags: terminology, prescription, labeling, dosage, med-symbol-abbreviations

I have 2 prescriptions of Predinisone, and on one of them it is written, "PredniSONE 5MG TAB WES" and on another one it is written, "PREDNISONE 10MG TAB CAD." Are they the same formula and only differ in the quantity in each tablet? What does CAD and WES means in this case. On another bottle of Acetaminophen (i think) it states "tab LEG".